# Add a compound index when some fields can be null or arrays of strings

Tags: mongodb, compound-index

I have a mongodb collection.

```
{
    "p1": "V1",
    "p2": ["V2","V3","V4"],
    "p3": ["V5","V6","V7"],
    "p4": "V8"
}
```

I want to create an index on fields `p1`, `p2`, `p3`. My documents may not have `p2` or `p3`. How should I create my index?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `p2` and `p3` may be missing or may be equal to `null`, I would go for a [sparse index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) like so :

`db.myCollection.createIndex( { p1:1, p2:1, p3:1 } , { sparse: true } )`

Answer (score 0):

According to your question it is clear that you are going to create a **compound multikey index** where two of them are array. But the limitation of `compound multikey index` is, it can have at most one indexed field whose value is an array.

> Compound Multikey Indexes For a compound multikey index, each indexed
>   document can have at most one indexed field whose value is an array.
>   As such, you cannot create a compound multikey index if more than one
>   to-be-indexed field of a document is an array. Or, if a compound
>   multikey index already exists, you cannot insert a document that would
>   violate this restriction.

So, according to **mongodb manual** you can take either `p1` or `p2` as indexed field.

learn more about **compound multikey index** from [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/)

Your document may not have indexed fields, In this case **Sparse Index** can be used.

For the given collection:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { p1:1, p2:1, p4:1 } , { sparse: true } )
```

will create an `Sparse Index`. But you have to consider the following limitations :

1. If any document does not contain the indexed field the sparse index will not contain an entry for that document.
2. Use of `hint` can solve the limitation 1 but you may get incomplete result.

You can learn more about sparse index from [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-index-incomplete-results)